# Non-syntactic characterization of $\Delta_0$ formulae

Tags: set-theory, constructive-mathematics, metalogic

A common schema in intuitionistic, constructive set theories is that of *$\it{\Delta_0}$ separation*:

$$
\forall x\exists y\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow z\in x\wedge\phi(x, z))\text{ provided $\phi$ is a $\Delta_0$ formula}
$$

So chosen as $\Delta_0$ sets are clearly predicatively defined, and full separation is known to be implied by $\mathsf{LEM}$, suggesting a non-intuitionistic nature to it. However [Aczel](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0049-237X(09)70120-X) provides a type-theoretic justification for a different separation principle, $\textit{small separation}$:

$$
\forall x\exists y\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow\exists w(w\in x\wedge\phi(x, w)\wedge w = z))
$$

with no restrictions on $\phi$. The latter is equivalent to the former without restriction on $\phi$ if $\phi$ is (internally) extensional in $w$ (that is, it is provable $w = z\rightarrow \phi(x, w)\leftrightarrow\phi(x, z)$), and specifically all $\Delta_0$ formulae are extensional by a routine induction on syntax. Thus, small separation implies all instances of $\Delta_0$ separation.

Does the converse hold, and if not, how might $\Delta_0$ separation be characterized non-syntactically, or the relative strengths of these axioms be compared?

---

It is known in classical $\mathsf{KP}$ that $\Delta_0$ separation implies stronger separation, in fact every instance of *absolute separation*, separation for absolute formulas. This is not known to be true of intuitionistic $\mathsf{KP}$, however it is known that $\mathsf{KP}$ and $\mathsf{CZF}$ are interpretable in each other, suggesting that at least relative to $\mathsf{CZF}$, absolute separation should hold. It's not then clear to me if and how absoluteness would apply to proving all instances of small separation.

Intuitively, to use small separation to show an element is in $y$, one would have to produce a witness for $w$. This should effectively bound all quantifiers in $\phi$ by the set of all "presently constructible" sets, restoring predicativity and suggesting that every application of small separation begets an equivalent application of $\Delta_0$ separation, but I'm suspicious that impredicativity has snuck in here and that a metatheoretic proof cannot be extracted from this argument.

Comment: Perhaps I’m misunderstanding something here, but it seems to me that $\exists w (w \in x \land \phi(x, w) \land w = z)$ is equivalent to $z \in x \land \phi(x, z)$. Thus, small separation is identical to normal separation.

Comment: @MarkSaving Predicate extensionality does not in general hold.

Semantically, restricted separation holds internal to any constructively well-pointed Heyting category but full separation does not, yet every such category can justify separation for extensional predicates. The question then is, in light of this, what are the implications of small separation? Justifying separation by syntactic induction is natural but there's something inherently impredicative about the argument.

Comment: It might be too late to answer, but it seems to me that small separation is stronger than the $\Delta_0$ separation (although I have no idea if we can state small separation over the language of set theory.) Small separation can imply more than the $\Delta_0$ separation if we are given more type constructors, like, impredicative types. As far as I remember, a type resembling Russell's reducibility axiom should imply both Powerset and Full Seperation, and the latter should follow from small separation.

Comment: You may find the detail about the reducibility axiom from Gambino's Laurea thesis (if you can find, you may need to contact him to get it.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes, small separation is equivalent to full separation. The relation to reducibility is an interesting parallel. Makes sense in light of the fact that most of my confusion boiled down to a misreading of separation over functions into small types as separation over all functions. Permitting functions into all well-founded types is the semantic content of reducibility and would recover, e.g., cumulative type universes.

Comment: I doubt small separation is equivalent to full separation in general, as Aczel's type-theoretic interpretation does not interpret full separation in general.

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes. Aczel's interpretation does not interpret small separation either. That was an erroneous claim on my part. Even predicative categorical models identify isomorphism and equality so I don't think there's an admissible interpretation of equality that doesn't render small separation equivalent to full separation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Delta_0$-separation admits a rather elegant semantic interpretation. We consider a first-order theory of categories with terminal elements. The sole predicate is equality on morphisms. A $\Delta_0$ formula in this theory is one in which for every quantifier there is an object $X$ for which the variable ranges over the morphisms $1\rightarrow X$.

**Structural $\Delta_0$-separation**
*For every $\Delta_0$ formula $\phi$, there exists a mono $s : S\rightarrowtail X$ such that $x : 1\rightarrow X$ factors through $s$ if and only if $\phi(x)$*

This can be expanded in the obvious way to full structural separation, with most of the sequel extending in the expected way to the usual consequences of inviting full separation into your set theory.

Structural $\Delta_0$ separation is a nice categorical property, as the following shows

**Theorem** [[Shulman](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3802.pdf)]
*A finitely complete category is Heyting and constructively well-pointed (that is, its initial object is a separator, projective, indecomposable, and admits no morphisms to the terminal object) if and only if it satisfies structural $\Delta_0$-separation.*

If objects interpret sets and their elements are identified with global elements, then this is a reasonable interpretation of material $\Delta_0$-separation in the sense that $S$ interprets $\{x\ |\ \phi(x)\}$ up to isomorphism. This can be made precise in the following sense:

**Theorem** [[Shulman](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3802.pdf)]
*A $\Pi$-pretopos* with an natural numbers object** satisfying $\Delta_0$-separation interprets a material set theory satisfying material $\Delta_0$-separation*

*I have intentionally copied this condition verbatim; my grasp on category theory is weak but I believe this is unnecessarily strong and a constructively well-pointed Heyting category would suffice

**Similar note. The finitist could probably do with only induction in the metatheory

This is not immediate, as our theory of categories only identifies sets up to isomorphism (even in $\mathbf{Set}$: this is a trivial consequence of having no predicate on objects). Instead the interpretation works by essentially abusing the natural numbers object to create a local W-type to interpret sets a la Aczel. Hamfisted, but effective.

Our first theorem gives assurance that $\Delta_0$ separation is the "right" notion of separation in predicative minimalism, as a constructively well-pointed Heyting category is an arguable semantic lower bound for set theories we might be interested in.

This is all good, but it doesn't really answer the question: I've only kicked the can down the road into a theory of categories. And to an extent, that's where it'll have to stay. the categorical perspective at least makes intuitively precise what the strength of $\Delta_0$-separation is: it is separation quantified over objects of the category, at least so far as there is enough internal structure to prove factorization. We have very few canonical choices left to extend the structure. We could add local cartesian closure, which would only be of interest in particularly weak theories, or we could add power objects/subobject classifiers, which bring us Boolean-ness away from $\mathbf{Set}$.

Besides this observation, being the strict lower bound specified by the constructively well-pointed Heyting category is in and of itself the best characterization of $\Delta_0$ formulae.

So what of small separation? How does it compare? Small separation doesn't admit a clear candidate for a structural analog, as objects cannot be identified beyond isomorphism, so separation holding up to isomorphism implies (at least up to laundering through the constructions of Shulman) that separation holds, which is demonstrably unconservative, both as it's known that full separation interprets second-order arithmetic, and that there are models of $\mathsf{CZF}$ refuting full separation (although, interestingly, not to my knowledge also refuting $\mathsf{REA}$, though they should exist as $\mathsf{CZF + REA}$ is interpretable in $\mathsf{KPi}$ which is weaker than second-order arithmetic).

This leaves us with the elephant in the room: if by every inspection small separation is separation, then I must be mistaken; what is *actually* justified by Aczel's interpretation?

The missing piece is that in Aczel's justification, the type interpreting $\phi$ must be small. As the type of sets is not small, unbounded quantification is interpreted by large $\Sigma$ types, whereas bounded quantifiers are small. Ergo, the justified separation formulas are precisely those with $\Delta_0$ $\phi$. A subtle point, but critical. This remains true even if full W-types are added to the type theory: semantically, this upgrades the model category to a $\Pi W$-pretopos, but still only justifying $\Delta_0$-separation (now stronger thanks to the additional objects). This explains semantically why $\mathsf{CZF + REA}$ for example does not explode in proof-theoretic strength.